# Export 2 HTML tables to Excel, in two worksheets with CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, angular, export-to-excel

I am developing  an Angular App.I need to export two html table to one excel file with two worksheets, each sheet with one table, and preserve the CSS Styles.

Now I reach export 2 tables to one excel file with two worksheets, but both tables are in the first sheet, and second sheet are empty.
Here my code:

```
exportTableToExcel() {
    var style = `<style>
    .table-header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .table-td-data {
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-td-data-2 {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-td-data-3 {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-td-title {
        background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        &.center-text {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }
    .table-td-title-center-text {
        background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-tr-spacer {
        height: 1rem;
    }</style>`;
    const uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        //template = `<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>${style}</head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>`,
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>',
        templateend = '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/>${style}</head>',
        body = '<body>',
        tablevar = '<table>{table',
        tablevarend = '}</table>',
        bodyend = '</body></html>',
        worksheet = '<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>',
        worksheetend = '</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>',
        worksheetvar = '{worksheet',
        worksheetvarend = '}',
        wstemplate_en = worksheet + worksheetvar + '_en' + worksheetvarend + worksheetend,// <x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet0}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>
        tabletemplate_en = tablevar + '_en' + tablevarend, // <table>{table0}</table>
        wstemplate_ca = worksheet + worksheetvar + '_ca' + worksheetvarend + worksheetend,// <x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet0}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>
        tabletemplate_ca = tablevar + '_ca' + tablevarend, // <table>{table0}</table>
        allTemplate = template + wstemplate_en + wstemplate_ca + templateend,
        allWorksheet = body + tabletemplate_en + tabletemplate_ca + bodyend,
        allOfIt = allTemplate + allWorksheet,
        base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
        format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) },
        table_en = this.excel_table_en.nativeElement,
        table_ca = this.excel_table_ca.nativeElement,
        ctx = {},
        link = document.createElement('a');
        
    ctx['worksheet_en'] = 'trafos_en';
    ctx['worksheet_ca'] = 'trafos_ca';
    ctx['table_en'] = table_en.outerHTML;
    ctx['table_ca'] = table_ca.outerHTML;

    link.download = `${this.trafoItem.code}.xls`;
    link.href = uri + base64(format(allOfIt, ctx));
    link.click();
}
```

It's seems that I create and Excel with two sheets, but copy the content of body to the first sheet, I don't have any idea how to fill the second sheet with a desired table.

In other case I reach to export the tables to excel, with two sheets, each sheets with one table, but the css styles are not applied

```
exportTableToExcel() {
    var style = `<style>
    .table-header {
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .table-td-data {
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-td-data-2 {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-td-data-3 {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-td-title {
        background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        &.center-text {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }
    .table-td-title-center-text {
        background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
        font-weight: 700;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .table-tr-spacer {
        height: 1rem;
    }</style>`;
    const uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
        + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
        + '<Styles>'
        + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
        + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
        + '</Styles>' 
        + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
        , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
        , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) },
        link = document.createElement('a');


    var ctx: any = null;
    var workbookXML = "";
    var worksheetsXML = "";
    var rowsXML = "";
    var tables = [this.excel_table_en.nativeElement, this.excel_table_ca.nativeElement];
    var wsnames = ['Worksheet_EN', 'Worksheet_CA'];
    var wbname = `${this.trafoItem.code}.xls`;
    var appname = 'Excel';
    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    //if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
            rowsXML += '<Row>'
            for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
                var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
                var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
                var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
                dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
                var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
                dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
                ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                        , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                        , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                        , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                        };
                rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
            }
            rowsXML += '</Row>'
        }
        ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";
    }

    ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
    workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

    link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
    link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
    link.target = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

In this case I don't now how define the Excel styles on each cell.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Also I have problems to export base64 images inserted in html table. When I created the Excel file, image is broken. I would be very grateful for your help.